# Logstash basic multiline filter not working?

Tags: regex, logstash

My log file begins as follows:

```
Node Name: StackOverflow
Node IP: 127.0.0.1
Logs: the name of my log
Logs Date: From 2016-06-12 To 2016-06-14
...
...
```

I am trying to join all of these lines in one filter by doing this in my conf:

```
input {
  file {
    path   => '[...]'
    start_position => beginning 
    ignore_older => 0 
    codec => multiline {
        pattern => "Log|Node"
        negate => "false"
        what => "previous"
    }
  }
}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

When doing so, I simply get the message "{:timestamp=>"2016-06-29T12:51:28.876000-0700", :message=>"Pipeline main started"}" and nothing is printed. If I change the pattern to be just "Log" or "Node", I do get some results, but obviously not exactly what I want. This seems very basic but I am stuck. Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is is hanging with that pattern is because that pattern matches all the lines, so it is trying to join them all to previous lines that do not match the pattern, which don't exist. The multiline codec should not match all your lines, it should either only match the delimiting line (beginning or end line) of a multiline log or every line that isn't a delimiter. If you match everything it will just join all your lines into one big event.

If all your logs will begin with `Node Name` you could change your pattern to

```
pattern => "^Node Name"
```

`^` matches a line beginning, ensuring that a log with the words Node Name in the middle doesn't ruin this.

and set

```
negate => "true"
```

Which will join all lines that do not start with "Node Name" to the line above them. Lines that start with "Node Name" will match the regex and thus will not be joined to lines above them, delimiting separate events.

Reference:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html

Comment: I still am not sure if I understand the problem, I want to join all these 4 lines together. I don't think adding the ^ helped for that issue. Why does the or statement not work?

Comment: Edited for a little more clarity, I stated why your pattern doesn't work at the top of my answer

Comment: Also it doesn't hurt to try the suggested solution before assuming it won't work ;)

Comment: Sorry, I guess I wrote my question incorrectly. There is actually more information in the log file, but it just begins with those 4 lines. I wouldn't want the rest of the lines to be added together.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your problem right, you want to join only the lines beginning with `Node IP:`, `Logs:` and `Logs Date:` to the lines beginning with `Node Name:`.

You could use this multiline :

```
multiline {
    pattern => "(Node IP:)|(Logs:)|(Logs Date:)"
    negate => "false"
    what => "previous"
}
```

It won't match the first line with `Node Name:`, but the other will be.